# How to get an ApplicationContext from createPackageContext()

Tags: android, android-context

The code is followed:

> Context c = getContext().createPackageContext("com.master.schedule",
>   Context.CONTEXT_INCLUDE_CODE|Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);
>
> int id = c.getResources().getIdentifier("layout_main", "layout","com.master.schedule");
>       LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
>       piflowView = inflater.inflate(id, null);

`com.master.schedule` is my package project.The upside code presents how the other project(his package name is different to mine) inflate my project, in my project there is only a ViewGroup(I don't have an activity); and when I invoke "`context.getApplicationContext`", it returns null...  my project code is below:

```
public class CascadeLayout extends RelativeLayout {
    private Context context;
    public CascadeLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context=context.getApplicationContext();
    }
     @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();
        //here: context == null;
    }
}
```

I find the `createPackageContext()` give the "`Context c`" to me is a `ContextImpl` type; I think that's caused return null;

So how can I get an ApplicationContext which not null？

BTW：please don't persuade me don't invoke `getApplicationContext();`As I must use an .jar, the jar need to invoke `getApplicationContext()` in it;

thanks very very much.

Comment: on what object you are calling `getApplicationContext()`? also you are using wrong package in your code...

Comment: Forgive my English expression, I have update my questions, where my context.getApplicationContext(); thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for [createPackageContext()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#createPackageContext(java.lang.String,%20int)) states:

> Return a new Context object for the given application name. This
>   Context is the same as what the named application gets when it is
>   launched, containing the same resources and class loader.

Reading a bit between the lines, this context is apparently supposed to be "the same" as an application context. However, you are seeing that its `getApplicationContext()` returns `null`, so we can attempt to fix that by using a [ContextWrapper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html) (see below). Hopefully, this approach will be good enough for your needs.

In the following code, `WrappedPackageContext` is used to wrap the "package context" returned by `createPackageContext()`, overriding the `getApplicationContext()` implementation so that it returns itself.

```
class WrappedPackageContext extends ContextWrapper {
    WrappedPackageContext(Context packageContext) {
        super(packageContext);
    }

    @Override
    public Context getApplicationContext() {
        return this;
    }
}

Context createApplicationContext(Context packageContext) {
    return new WrappedPackageContext(packageContext);
}
```

Comment: I do it like this, and now it does work. Thanks u r so witty~